# Can I use eth in azure blockchain service?

Tags: azure, quorum, azure-blockchain-service

I what to use eth in azure blockchain service with quorum protocol.

When I started azure blockchain service, my member's default balance was 0 eth.

How to set default eth or how to set genesis block ??

Comment: Yes, there is option for selecting blockchain.

Comment: Where can I do that?

Comment: Currently you can only select Quorum with Azure Blockchain Service. 
From their documentation "Azure Blockchain Service is designed to support multiple ledger protocols. Currently, it provides support for the Ethereum Quorum ledger using the IBFT consensus mechanism."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/blockchain/service/overview